# Need Advanced Gmail Filter to Auto-Delete Some Spam

Tags: gmail

I'm pulling email from a non-Gmail account into my Gmail inbox.  Unfortunately, that account gets a lot of spam but Gmail correctly moves it to the "spam" pseudo-folder.

I'd like to know if there's a way to set up a filter with the equivalent of this query: "If message addressed to [my non-Gmail account address] AND in:spam" and then have the filter auto delete any matching messages.

I know I can manually view spam, select all, and delete, but I'd rather have a filter do it.  That way, the only remaining spam is from my regular account, which I like to do a quick scan on before deleting in case there are any false positives.

Gmail's filtering either doesn't seem to allow for "in:spam" type qualifiers or won't auto-execute such a filter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail warns you that the "is" operator will not match on incoming mail, but actually it works perfectly well at the moment.  I use it in my filters, and so do other people (example:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31042/how-can-i-auto-delete-some-spam-from-gmail).